# Join string before, between, and after

Tags: python, string

Suppose I have this list:

```
lis = ['a','b','c','d']
```

If I do `'x'.join(lis)` the result is:

```
'axbxcxd'
```

What would be a clean, simple way to get this output?

```
'xaxbxcxdx'
```

I could write a helper function:

```
def joiner(s, it):
    return s+s.join(it)+s
```

and call it like `joiner('x',lis)` which returns `xaxbxcxdx`, but it doesn't look as clean as it could be. Is there a better way to get this result?

Comment: I think whether you are doing `s+s.join(it)+s` or `join([''] + lis + [''])` does not really matter. In any case, since `join` does not directly do what you want, you have to prepend and append something to your list.

Comment: @Jan-PhilipGehrcke `[''] + lis -> new list`, `new list + [''] -> second new list`, then `join`. I think, it is better to use `itertools.chain`

Answer (score 34, accepted):

```
>>> '{1}{0}{1}'.format(s.join(lis), s)
'xaxbxcxdx'
```

Comment: I would not say that this is *so* much better than the other answer.

Comment: @Jan-PhilipGehrcke I like this primarily because it is so flexible - it's very easy to adapt in the future if needed, the other answer somewhat less so.

Answer (score 18):

You can join a list that begins and ends with an empty string:

```
>>> 'x'.join(['', *lis, ''])
'xaxbxcxdx'
```

Comment: Nice ... and simple!

Answer (score 4):

You can use f-string:

```
s = 'x'
f'{s}{s.join(lis)}{s}'
```

In Python 3.8 you can also use the walrus operator:

```
f"{(s:='x')}{s.join(lis)}{s}"
```

or

```
(s:='x') + s.join(lis) + s
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `str.replace()` to interleave the characters:

```
>>> lis = ['a','b','c','d']
>>> ''.join(lis).replace('', 'x')
'xaxbxcxdx'
```

On the other hand, your original solution (or a trivial modification with string formatting) is IMO actually pretty clean and readable.

Comment: Nice but this doesn't work if the elements in the list have multiple characters: doing it on a list foo bar would give xfxoxoxbxaxrx and not xfooxbarx.

Comment: @Basj Agreed, i wouldn't use this in Production code anyway. The OP's solution is quite reasonable as I said

Answer (score 1):

You may also do it as

```
'x'.join([''] + lis + [''])
```

But I'm not sure if it's cleaner.

It will produce only 1 separator on empty list instead of 2 as one in the question.

Comment: The main reason for wanting this is to not have `'x'` littered three times. `'x'` in my application is a bit longer string. This helps, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

A generator can interleave the characters, and the result can be `join`ed without having to create intermediate strings.

```py
L = list('abcd')

def mixer(chars, insert):
    yield insert
    for char in chars:
        yield char
        yield insert

result = ''.join(mixer(L, 'x'))  # -> 'xaxbxcxdx'
```

While it isn't a one-liner, I think it is clean and simple, unlike these `itertools` creations that I came up with initially:

```py
from itertools import repeat, starmap, zip_longest
from operator import add

# L must have a len, so doesn't work with generators
''.join(a for b in itertools.zip_longest(repeat('x', len(L) + 1),
                                             L, fillvalue='')
            for a in b)

# As above, and worse still creates lots of intermediate strings
''.join(starmap(add, zip_longest(repeat('x', len(L) + 1), L, fillvalue='')))
```

Answer (score 0):

Arguably there is a much simpler approach to be found here - just add the character before and after your join function. Others have suggested f-strings, which is a fancy way of achieving the same thing. String concatenation is also fine:

```
lis = ['a','b','c','d']
lis_str = 'x' + 'x'.join(lis) + 'x'
```

If your string is long and you don't want to repeat it multiple times, you can just put this into a variable and do the same thing

```
lis = ['a','b','c','d']
join_str = 'x-marks-the-spot'
lis_str = join_str + join_str.join(lis) + join_str
```